# survIDINRI package ERROR res.IDI.INF function R

Tags: r, error-handling, cox-regression

I'm trying to calculate the integrated discrimination improvement for two Cox regression models (time, event), using the survIDINRI package and the res.IDI.INF function. However, I'm get an error message pointing towards an NA/NaN/Inf problem.

This is the code for the function:

```
#time = numeric (years) (max 15 years)
#event, censored = 0, event = 1
res.IDI.INF <- IDI.INF(indata = data[,c("time","event")],
                       covs0,          
                       covs1,
                       t0 = 15,
                       npert = 300, npert.rand = NULL, seed1 = NULL, alpha = 0.05)
IDI.INF.OUT(res.IDI.INF)
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Error in unoecdf(cc, pdiff[case], Wi[case] * PTB.Vi[case]) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
```

Would be great if there is a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer is not too late but maybe the cause of your problem comes from the argument "t0" in the function. I think that this argument must be in days and not in years, try to write t0 = 15*365, I think that it should work :)

Good luck